# What is an efficient way of creating a "network" from identifier data in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am a newbie in python and after browsing several answers to various questions concerning loops in python/pandas, I remain confused on how to solve my problem concerning water management data. I am trying to categorise and aggregate data based on its position in the sequence of connected nodes. The "network" is formed by each node containing the ID of the node that is downstream.

The original data contains roughly 53 000 items, which I converted to a pandas dataframe and looks something like this:

```
subwatershedsID = pd.DataFrame({ 'ID' : ['649208-127140','649252-127305','650556-126105','687315-128898'],'ID_DOWN' : ['582500-113890','649208-127140','649252-127305','574050-114780'], 'OUTLET_ID' : ['582500-113890','582500-113890','582500-113890','574050-114780'], 'CATCH_ID' : [217,217,217,213] })
```

My naive approach to deal with the data closest to the coast illustrates what I am trying to achieve.

```
sbwtrshdNextToStretch = subwatershedsID.loc[subwatershedsID['ID_DOWN'] == subwatershedsID['OUTLET_ID']] 
sbwtrshdNextToStretchID = sbwtrshdNextToStretch[['ID']] 
sbwtrshdStepFurther = pd.merge(sbwtrshdNextToStretchID, subwatershedsID, how='inner', left_on='ID', right_on='ID_DOWN')
sbwtrshdStepFurther.rename(columns={'ID_y': 'ID'}, inplace=True)
sbwtrshdStepFurtherID = sbwtrshdStepFurther[['ID']] 
sbwtrshdTwoStepsFurther = pd.merge(sbwtrshdStepFurtherID, subwatershedsID, how='inner', left_on='ID', right_on='ID_DOWN')
sbwtrshdTwoStepsFurther.rename(columns={'ID_y': 'ID'}, inplace=True)
sbwtrshdTwoStepsFurtherID = sbwtrshdTwoStepsFurther[['ID']] 
subwatershedsAll = [sbwtrshdNextToStretchID, sbwtrshdStepFurtherID, sbwtrshdTwoStepsFurtherID] 
subwatershedWithDistances = pd.concat(subwatershedsAll,  keys=['d0', 'd1', 'd2'])
```

So this gives each node an identifier on how many nodes away it is from the first one and it feels like there should be a more simple way to achieve it and obviously something that works better for the whole data that can be with large number of consecutive connections.  However, my thoughts are continuously returning to writing a loop within a loop, but all the advise seems to recommend avoiding them and hence also discourages from learning how to write the loop correctly. Furthermore, the comments on poor loop performance leave me with further doubts, since I am not sure how fast solving for 53 000 rows would be. So what would be a good python style solution?

Comment: Hi @janne - it's a complex question so I'm not able to offer a specific answer but in my experience Pandas doesn't have anything in it that's specifically helpful for network analysis. You might have some success with https://networkx.github.io/ which is designed for network analysis. Alternatively, if you want to loop then a simpler structure (eg a dictionary) might help.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you have two stages:

1. Categorise each node based on its position in the network
2. Perform calculations on the data to work out things like volumes of water, number of nodes a certain distance from the outlet, etc.

If so...

**1) Use NetworkX to perform the calculations on relative position in the network**

NetworkX is a great network analysis library that comes with ready-made methods to achieve this kind of thing.

Here's an example using dummy data:

```
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from([1,2,3,4])
G.add_edges_from([(1,2),(2,3),(3,4)])
# In this example, the shortest path is all the way down the stream
nx.shortest_path(G,1,4)
> [1,2,3,4]
len(nx.shortest_path(G,1,4))
> 4
# I've shortened the path by adding a new 'edge' (connection) between 1 and 4
G.add_edges_from([(1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(1,4)])
# Result is a much shorter path of only two nodes - the source and target
nx.shortest_path(G,1,4)
> [1,4]
len(nx.shortest_path(G,1,4))
> 2
```

**2) Annotate the dataframe for later calculations**

Once you have this data in a network format, you can iterate through the data and add that as metadata to the `DataFrame`.

Comment: NetworkX also has methods that you can use to calculate all shortest paths to all nodes connected to a single node, which would give you all the paths upstream from an outlet in a single command: https://networkx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.unweighted.single_source_shortest_path.html#networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.unweighted.single_source_shortest_path

Comment: Interesting. The choice between single and all is not so great, though.  Is there some way of using a set of predefined destinations?